# Is there a way to assign Assistant to nodes in a OrgChart based on D3.js?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts

I'm not familiar with D3.js and can't figure out how to assign assistant roles to nodes in an Org Chart. Any chance that is possible?

I'm trying to create an Organizational Chart based on D3.js and what I need to do is to asign Assistant roles for some of the nodes in my chart. I know some js, but I've never created a project like this one. Also I'm not attached to D3. I'm open to any other kind of solution as long as the work can be done.

Thanks in advance to anybody willing to help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BALKAN OrgChartJS, it has assistant node types, see https://code.balkan.app/org-chart-js/assistant#JS

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm working at BALKAN App and I'm one of the developers of of the suggested library

Comment: First of all, thanks for your kind answer. 
Secondly, I have doubts about the use of Balkan. I was trying it first, but the library stopped working for me, the error message was the demo period had ended. Does it has a free version?

Comment: In case you want to use it for longer period you can ask to extend your trial, there is no free version